# Built in iteration counter for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

I would like to iterate through a list and reference the iteration number that I'm on. I can do it with a simple counter, but is there a built in function for this?

```
List= list(range(0,6))
count = 0
for item in List:
    print "This is interation ", str(count)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Its what that [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is for !

> [enumerate(sequence, start=0)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)
>
> Return an enumerate object. sequence must be a sequence, an iterator, or >some other object which supports iteration.

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
```

And in iteration you can do :

```
for index,element in enumerate(seasons):
     #do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built-in function [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).